# Is the following snippet valid Bourne shell code?

Tags: bash, syntax-error, sh

The following snippet triggers a syntax error when interpreted by **bash**  4.3.39(1) but not by **zsh** 5.0.5.

```
eprintf()
{
    1>&2 {
        printf "$@"
        printf '\n'
    }
}
```

Have I just found a bug in **bash** parser?

Comment: Odd. It seems like bash interprets the first close brace as the end of the function...

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Please report it.

Comment: Out of interest, does this work as expected if you move the redirection to after the block? I can't find anything in the spec to support it but http://shellcheck.net only complains about the variable in the format string when this change is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug; from the man page:

> The following redirection operators may precede or  appear
>          anywhere within a **simple** command or may follow a command.

So

```
>/dev/null echo foo
echo >/dev/null foo
echo foo >/dev/null
```

are all legal and equivalent, but the redirection must follow the compound command `{...}`.

Because `{` has no real special meaning to `bash` (`alias {=foo` makes `{` and alias for `foo`), the line `1>&2 {` is parsed as a simple command, with the assumption that the lookup for `{` will succeed when `eprintf` is eventually called. As a result, the first `}` closes the compound statement serving as the body of the function, and the second one is unmatched and triggers the syntax error.

I couldn't say without further research *why* `bash` and `zsh` differ here, only that it is documented behavior for `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for writing the answer, the bash team prompted me to the man page, were I found the paragraph you quote. It is very strange, to say the least! Luckily enough, Shellcheck catches the error!

Comment: Yeah, you usually have to read the man page very carefully to pick up on the subtleties. I was in the middle of writing up an answer about why this *was* a bug when I finally noticed the difference in usage for simple and compound commands :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Single Unix Specification, Shell and Utilities Volume, the function definition command syntax is:

```
fname() compound-command[io-redirect ...]
```

In your case that would give:

```
eprintf() { printf "$@" ; printf '\n' } >&2
```

The function definition command syntax only allows for one compound command, moreover, compound commands ( `{ ... }` ) do not have any io redirection mentioned in the syntax, functions do.

So according to my reading of the standard, this really doesn't look much like a bug.

Comment: The question is about a redirection on a compound statement inside a function, not a redirection on the body of the function itself. There's nothing preventing you from putting one compound statement inside another.

Comment: Redirection for the function is mentioned specially because it is applied when the function is *called*, not when the function is defined.  (Also, because function definitions are syntactically different from commands.) Redirections can be applied to any command, whether it is simple or compound (which includes `{...}`, `(...)`, `if`, `while`, `until`, `case`, and others).

Comment: @chepner My answer was wrong on the point that compound commands do accept redirections at the *end* of such a compound command (redirections inside the compound command do override the compound command redirections). IMO it is syntactically incorrect (in bourne shell) to specify the IO redirection before the (compound) command: prepending the IO redirection is something I consider a "bashism", so not necessarily valid bourne shell code. Then again, it all depends on agreeing what exactly is "bourne shell". The same goes for nesting compound commands. If I read the spec correctly: invalid.

Comment: Given that the question is if this is a bug in the `bash` parser, I'm treating the title as a typo.